# How to check for external entities in a set of XML files

Tags: xml

In order to avoid [a whole class of security vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing), I want to disable external entity expansion when parsing XML documents in my application.

However, I want to ensure that we don't have any code that depends on this behaviour, first.

We have good unit test coverage, using a large number of XML files, so if none of these include external entities, then I am fairly certain that it will be safe to disable this feature in the XML parser.

**My question:** What can I can search for in order to catch all potential uses of external entities in our test data?

It can be a straight string-search or a regex, if necessary.  It can also be a set of searches if that is simpler (I'd rather an easy-to-understand set of 4 strings to search for, than a single regex covering four variants).

I don't mind if the search returns false-positives provided there is a simple visual inspection that can be done to determine that they are false positives (e.g. must contain a URL), but there mustn't be any false negatives (i.e. I don't want to miss anything).

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing them using a SAX parser having first set an EntityResolver to intercept calls for external entity resolution.